# Use one scrollbar for all page content

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating a one page website with three screens, each one has a title section on the left and a content section on the right.

```
  <article class="first" >
     <aside class="left_first">
       <h4 class="title">Title</h4>
     </aside>
     <section class="right_first">
       <p>Scrollable content</p>
     </section>
  </article>
  <article class="second" >
     <aside class="left_second">
       <h4 class="title">Title</h4>
     </aside>
     <section class="right_second">
       <p>Scrollable content</p>
     </section>
  </article>
  <article class="third" >
     <aside class="left_third">
       <h4 class="title">Title</h4>
     </aside>
     <section class="right_third">
       <p>Scrollable content</p>
     </section>
  </article>
```

I want to remove all the scroll bars from the sections and make them scroll with the page, like every time the user scrolls down, the left half is fixed and the right will continue to scroll to show all the content then it will continue to the second screen and so on. I tried to find a way but I couldn't. So if anyone have an idea how to achieve this please let me know.
Thank you in advance

Comment: present a fiddle maybe ?

Comment: In fact, what you want is the default behavior  ??

Comment: As far as I understood the asides should not scroll smoothly but only change to the next aside during the scrolling when the corresponding section is finished scrolling through ...

Comment: @Hans Gerber Yes exactly.  The default behaviour is that the section is scrollable only when you hover it.

Comment: @marmar please add your remaining codes.

Comment: Well I think what comes closest to what you are trying to do would be something like fullpage.js (http://www.alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/)

Comment: The effect that I need to achieve is very similar to this one http://melaniedaveid.com/

Comment: If it helps here's a fiddle of my original code (all the code is inside the html area .. couldn't get that fiddle to work another way ^^*)
https://jsfiddle.net/paq3p06e/

Comment: @marmar check my answer below. i hope that's what you were looking for. let me know in a comment ;) thanks

Answer (score 0):

Made a snippet below or > https://jsfiddle.net/mvhu8cd5/

Explanation :

**CSS** .
I `floated` the `aside` and the `section` giving them `20%` and `80%` ( that's purely my choice, you can change these values how you want but they need to add up to `100%` )

**JQ**

On `scroll` , for each `article` I got the `offset().top`  values( distance from the top of the div to the top of the document ) , `height()` values  and found the `aside` and `section` divs inside each of the `articles` , and all of this stored in variables.

also stored the scrolled distance ( `scrollTop()` )

Then, I've made an if statement with 2 conditions.

*Condition 1* `b > a` , that means that the distance scrolled must be greater than the top offset of the article

*Condition 2* `b < a+c` , which means that the distance scrolled must be lesser than the top offset + height of article

If these 2 conditions are met , then I add class `fixed` to the `aside` and class `giveMargin` to the `section` . when these 2 conditions return FALSE, these 2 custom classes are removed.

*Ofcourse the JQ can be easily adjusted if you want changes*

**CSS part2**

Added styles to the 2 custom classes.
`position:fixed` to `aside.fixed` and `margin-left:20%` to `section.giveMargin`

Added that margin-left because by giving `position:fixed` to the `aside` , it's width does not influence the structure, so because the `20%` width ' disappears `  it needs to be replaced with something else. adding the margin does that and keeps the same structure as before

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  
       $("article").each(function(){
             var a = $(this).offset().top ,
             b = $(window).scrollTop(),
             c = $(this).height(),
             title = $(this).children("aside"),
             text = $(this).children("section")
           if (b > a && b < a+c ) {
                 $(title).addClass("fixed")
                 $(text).addClass("giveMargin")
           }else{
                $(title).removeClass("fixed")
                $(text).removeClass("giveMargin")
           }
       })
       })
```

```css
aside,section { float:left}
aside { width:20%;}
section { width:80%;}
article { width:100%;float:left;}

aside.fixed { position:fixed;top:0}
section.giveMargin { margin-left:20%}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article class="first" >
     <aside class="left_first">
       <h4 class="title">Title 1</h4>
     </aside>
     <section class="right_first">
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, porta tincidunt maecenas lectus sit, risus justo, penatibus ultrices tempor ornare pretium quis, congue duis orci. Nibh placerat lobortis dui quis lobortis, maecenas orci congue habitasse vestibulum in, lacus ea nunc pellentesque fermentum, aenean porttitor sem aliqua mattis vestibulum. Molestie consequat, curabitur integer viverra, at ante neque integer phasellus at, tortor massa mauris. Erat quis ac quam amet felis, nibh ligula ut quis, eleifend scelerisque in at at scelerisque. Vulputate vehicula laboris, est quis, tristique ultrices.</p>
     </section>
  </article>
  <article class="second" >
     <aside class="left_second">
       <h4 class="title">Title 2</h4>
     </aside>
     <section class="right_second">
       <p>Sagittis nullam magna eget, integer at ut netus elementum sed quis, vulputate dui quisque lobortis conubia. In a duis semper leo ante mi, vitae ut vitae nec lacus, tortor quisque vel, vel nisl pellentesque magna suspendisse dictum non, eu laoreet sodales. Nunc sollicitudin, vehicula placerat. In nunc donec arcu, in purus ac facilisis congue, arcu donec arcu enim dapibus, amet consectetuer. Erat wisi erat, nisl id iaculis maecenas, lectus enim eget elementum, adipiscing ultricies orci elit laoreet. Lorem pellentesque volutpat, id risus nulla ante, duis id, viverra et neque eget nulla lacinia, ac enim nunc justo enim sociosqu. Congue orci, lacus massa nunc accumsan dui, mauris ut proin in. Quis convallis nam at magna laoreet dolor. Curabitur cras nisl sollicitudin eget mi massa, arcu dolor ac vitae ut pellentesque amet. A felis vel conubia mattis, magna tempor est nibh tortor cras id, luctus sed nisl ornare. Porta ut aenean, eget in, maecenas tristique lectus.</p>
     </section>
  </article>
  <article class="third" >
     <aside class="left_third">
       <h4 class="title">Title 3</h4>
     </aside>
     <section class="right_third">
       <p>Penatibus pede, convallis dolor, augue porta lectus libero, nam sed. Nunc suspendisse erat scelerisque vestibulum, id ultricies urna et, tortor lacus varius sagittis pellentesque. Ut sollicitudin arcu, lobortis pretium, amet eu aliquam, vivamus sodales tempor, vestibulum wisi orci mi mauris arcu et. Suscipit auctor elementum, tellus arcu diam exercitation at, orci sapien eget sollicitudin ut vivamus amet. Posuere eget dapibus tortor, tortor pede mollis pede, nihil elit vitae. Quis id maecenas neque congue ut, mi nunc amet, ligula vel diam donec quam justo vitae. Nec tellus lectus ut, pulvinar nulla massa adipiscing, odio dui eleifend tellus id tortor hendrerit. Pede ante in suscipit augue, vestibulum dui, pellentesque risus faucibus.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, porta tincidunt maecenas lectus sit, risus justo, penatibus ultrices tempor ornare pretium quis, congue duis orci. Nibh placerat lobortis dui quis lobortis, maecenas orci congue habitasse vestibulum in, lacus ea nunc pellentesque fermentum, aenean porttitor sem aliqua mattis vestibulum. Molestie consequat, curabitur integer viverra, at ante neque integer phasellus at, tortor massa mauris. Erat quis ac quam amet felis, nibh ligula ut quis, eleifend scelerisque in at at scelerisque. Vulputate vehicula laboris, est quis, tristique ultrices.</p>
     </section>
  </article>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help but sadly it's not working for my case I tried to modify your snippet to make my self more clear. https://jsfiddle.net/marmarnassouf/1eyxjvpd/2/             as you can see when the cursor is hovering the aside I can't scroll the content section and I still have three inner scrollbar

Comment: so how exactly would you want it to work ? scroll INSIDE the content, and the title remains fixed on the left ?

Comment: @ Mihai T yes, it's very similar to this effect  http://melaniedaveid.com/    I need the inner scrollbars be hidden and the sections to scroll with the aside fixed until the content is finished then the next aside is shown and fixed until the content is shown

Comment: @marmar https://jsfiddle.net/mvhu8cd5/7/ see this fiddle. is this what you were looking for ? i've set `max-height:100px` to `.container` but if you want the effect from that site i suggest you use `max-height:100vh`

Comment: @ Mihai I really appreciate your effort. I applied the solution you gave me on this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/marmarnassouf/dzsb7vfs/  but I still can't scroll the content if the mouse cursor is over the aside so you must put the cursor on top of the content for it to scroll and the scrollbars are not hidden.

Comment: in your fiddle you didn't add jQuery . maybe that's why it doesn't work. i can't really check it now :)